# Exception thrown by BindingSource.MoveNext Cancels the edited value on the datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I 've run into the following situation:

```
    try
    {
        Validate();
        myBindingSource.MoveNext();
    }
    catch
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to keep editing the record?", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            myBindingSource.CancelEdit();
        }                
    }
```

where myBindingSource.Datasource is a DataTable and the databound textbox updates on validation.

I change the databound textbox of the current record to an invalid state (e.g. duplicate primary key). and when I call the code snippet above naturally an exception is thrown.

In the catch block the value of the field of the row of the datable has reverted to its original value but the textbox value remains the same (I want the same textbox value).

If I call the same snippet again no exception is thrown (DataTable has a correct value).

My question is how do I make textbox to send its data again to the DataTable?

P.S. if after the first calling of the code snippet change the value of textbox the DataSet receives the changes.

Comment: Wouldn't you need an Else after the MessageBox if they Select Yes..? where is the rest of the code..?

Comment: also what type of Exception are you catching in the try{}catch{} statement..? what you want to do is store the text in a property or other Protected variable and then call the method that sends the data again.. if I am understanding you correctly..

Comment: catch {} catches all Exceptions. The else part is missing because I don't know what to do to revert DataTable to each previous state. While textbox event 'Validating' is triggered both times the second time the validation does not cause the DataTable to get the textbox.Text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is the following (Though it writes back all the databound controls to the datasource. At least it keeps the datasource and the controls in synch):

```
try
{
    Validate();
    myBindingSource.MoveNext();
}
catch
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to keep editing the record?", "Error",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        myBindingSource.CancelEdit();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (Binding b in myBindingSource.CurrencyManager.Bindings)
                {
                    b.WriteValue();
                }
    }                
}
```